# http in the Location-header when the original request was made over https

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, tomcat, https, tomcat6

I am currently implementing `https` on our production environment, but I am scratching my head over a little thing here.

SSL is terminated in the load balancer and the flow in our stack is basically like this:

**Production**: Browser <- `https` -> Load balancer <- `http` -> Apache <- `http` -> Load balancer <- `http` -> Tomcat

**Testing**: Browser <- `https` -> nginx <- `http` -> Load balancer <- `http` -> Tomcat

When I access our login-page over HTTPS:

**Request headers**

```
POST /login/form HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 74
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://www.example.org
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://www.example.org/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: nb,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

**Response headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 11:16:50 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: FOO=example
Location: http://www.example.org/portal
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

I talked to a developer and he told me the following:

> In the code there is sth like request.sendRedirect("/portal") and Tomcat does the rest.

I am able to reproduce the problem on the testing environment, although a bit different stack.

My questions:

1. Why do I get `http` as the scheme in the `Location`-header when the original request from the browser was made with `https`?
2. Is this an Apache mod_rewrite/mod_proxy or nginx problem?
3. Is this a problem with Tomcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get http in the response headers because the request that reaches Apache is HTTP - the SSL has been stripped away at the load balancer.  So from what Apache sees, it's just an HTTP request.

You can work around this by setting

```
ServerName https://www.example.org
```

in the global or virtual host configuration.  This will override the default http scheme so Apache will send the response you want.  The documentation for [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) mentions this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On our testing-environment we have nginx instead of Apache. Do you know how to set it there?

Comment: Afraid not, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue. Adding the following in your virtualhost config should solve the problem. Basically it would edit the http request to https

`Header edit Location ^http://(.*)$ https://$1`

Answer (score 2):

http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

```
proxy_redirect default;
proxy_redirect http://www.example.org/ https://www.example.org/;
```